# How to use onEachFeature in Leaflet.js map?

Tags: leaflet

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adelaide01/2b4qfv66/3/) and I am trying to implement onEachFeature (at the bottom) of the code.

Each polygon has its own popupContent as in the [onEachFeature tutorial shown on Leaflet.js.com](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

However, I get stuck trying to merge together these pieces of code:

```
var myGeoJson = L.geoJson(myData, {
  style: style
}).addTo(map).bindPopup("test");
var popup = L.popup();


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
}

var myGeoJson = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Ultimately, I'm just trying to pass in the features.properties.popupContent as a variable any way possible without losing my style properties (fill color, etc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adampax/r8ktzrkz/).

You are close with the code. You can pass `style` and `onEachFeature`:

```
var myGeoJson = L.geoJson(myData, {
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Also, in `myData`, one of the features had a property called `name` instead of `popupContent`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. And the link to your fiddle with the answer is actually https://jsfiddle.net/adampax/r8ktzrkz/1/  as in version 1.

Comment: This was very useful, thank you. How would you do it if you had an external geojson file? E.g. if you were calling filename.geojson instead of assigning it to a variable (like myData in OP's example)?

Comment: That, of course, should be a new question :-)